# Python - Is there a quick method with Numpy for matrix multiplication

Tags: python, numpy, numba

Hey I would have a question. I have currently written part of my code in Numba. For each individual element from my binary matrix its 3x3 neighborhood [i-1: i + 2, j-2: j + 2] should be taken. I multiply this neighborhood by a matrix [[64, 128, 1], [32, 0, 2], [16, 8, 4]] and form the sum.
I know Numba doesn't get along with Numpy very well in some places. Is there a Numpy function to perform exactly this function for all elements from my NxM matrix?
As far as I am concerned, the results could be saved as intermediate results in another matrix and later called up using an index.

```
    for i in prange(1, h - 1):
        for j in range(1, w - 1):
            neighbor = lastResult[i - 1 : i + 2, j - 1 : j + 2]
            x = sum(nb * pattern)
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: im pretty sure that there is a method called `dot` for numpy arrays. tag it onto the end of an array and pass in the array that you want to multiply. Is this what you mean by multiplying?

Comment: I tried the ``dot`` method before too, but I get some error. I don't know how I can fix this. And would this one much faster as ``x = np.sum(nb * pattern)``?

Comment: @Bayezid You might want to address someone so they get notified. Also, [mre] please.

Comment: @arandomcoder ``dot`` dot is not working becasue it's a matrix multiplication. I need a function that multiply A * B like =a1*b1 a2*b2 ... . The same method from NumPy was ``np.multiply``. But I have the same result. So okay. I think it's exists no other methods to do it faster in this point.

Comment: @superbitch Sorry was the first time that I used Stackoverflow. But thanks for this info.

Comment: @paisanco this post is not helping me by my problem. But thanks.

Comment: I guess You could take the sum of `64 * lastResult[:-2, :-2]` and the other eight.

Comment: @superbitch another question. Does a method exists to get only the outline elements ofa a matrix? ex. [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11, 12]] To get the Value of 1 2 3 4 5 8 9 10 11 12?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are computing a convolution. It looks like numpy has a function for 1-d (array) convolutions ([link](https://numpy.org/doc/1.19/reference/generated/numpy.convolve.html)). Scipy supports 2-d (matrix) convolutions ([link](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.convolve2d.html)).

From the documentation, it looks like you would use the convolve2d function as follows, where A is your MxN matrix and h is the 3x3 matrix you want to multiply each window in A by.

```
result=scipy.signal.convolve2d(A, h, mode='same', boundary='fill', fillvalue=0)
```

result will contain the sum of the 3x3 neighborhood around element i,j of the original matrix A after each element has been multiplied by the corresponding value in h.

Comment: Is the Numpy convolce method the same like SciPy?

Comment: I get the same result but it's double slower as when I use my method in top with numba. I can't combine SciPy with Numba that is the Problem. Numba helps me to iterate over the image parallel

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps scale and add like this?

```
import numpy as np

a = np.random.randint(2, size=(10, 10))
print(a)

s = slice(None, -2)
t = slice(1, -1)
u = slice(2, None)
print(
     64 * a[s, s] + 128 * a[s, t] + 1 * a[s, u] +
     32 * a[t, s] +                 2 * a[t, u] +
     16 * a[u, s] +   8 * a[u, t] + 4 * a[u, u]
)
```

Demo output:

```
[[0 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 0]
 [0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 1]
 [1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0]
 [0 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 1]
 [0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 1]
 [1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0]
 [0 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 1 0]
 [1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1]
 [1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1]
 [0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1]]
[[ 29 154  83 160  96   7 141 250]
 [ 46  57 181 200  80   3 130 101]
 [207 252 122  16  32   5 137 214]
 [159 254 125 188  92  30  24  51]
 [167 235 246 110  58  51 164 105]
 [211 197 235 211 225 225 198  76]
 [ 61 158  89 177 192  64   3 134]
 [110  63 188 124  28  24  21 143]]
```